# Ember JS: Call component action from another component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember JS and after looking through the doc I still have no idea or don't understand how to achieve the following.

I have a navbar component that includes a menu button component

```
//components/nav-bar.hbs

<nav>
   <LinkTo class="btn-1" @route="contact"><span>Contact</span></LinkTo>
   <LinkTo class="btn-1" @route="about"><span>About</span></LinkTo>
   <MenuButton>Menu</MenuButton>
</nav>
```

When this button is clicked I would like to toggle another component **which is not a parent nor a child of menu-button component, nor of the nav-bar component**

```
//components/nav-aside.hbs
<div class="core_page_cover">

</div>
<aside class="core_menu_aside">

</aside>


//components/nav-aside.js
import Component from "@glimmer/component";
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class NavAsideComponent extends Component {
   @action
   toggle() {
       //toggle expanded | retracted class
   }
}
```

I have no idea how to call the `toggle` action when clicking on the button and I guess I am missing something...

The components are encapsulated like so

```
// .--------------navbar.hbs--------------    //
// <nav>
//   link link link link link link toggle-button  //
// </nav>
// <MenuAside/>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain how these two components are related?

Comment: They are both inside navbar component... So far I tried really hard to understand the data down actions up system of ember octane and i must say that the learning curve is super steep and the documentation is lacking a lot of details... I updated to add a scheme of the situation.

Comment: I assume in your updated example, you meant to type `<NavAside/>` instead of `<MenuAside/>`? For further clarification, you want `<NavAside/>` to appear or disappear after clicking the toggle button in `<Navbar/>`?

Comment: @user3491125 It sounds like you are at the wrong track to be honest. What is your state that you are trying to manage? What part of your application should own that state? The part that owns the state (e.g. parent component, route controller or global service) should pass it down to the consumers together with a method that could be triggered to update it. That's what action up, data down is about. If it is about routing you may also want to consider using the `router` services, which exposes the routing state (e.g. `currentRoute`) together with method to update it (e.g. `transitionTo()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to move the state and the action to the common ancestor.

It seems you have 3 components:

- `navbar`
- `nav-bar`
- `nav-aside`

Where basically `navbar` encapsulates both `nav-bar` and `nav-aside`:

so you have basically this in your `navbar`:

```
<NavBar />
<NavAside />
```

and inside the `nav-bar` you have a button that should toggle if something inside `nav-aside` is shown.
Then the solution is to keep that information on the wrapping `navbar` component:

```
class NavbarComponent extends Component {
  @tracked showSomethingInAside = false;

  @action
  toggleShowSomethingInAside() {
    this.showSomethingInAside = !this.showSomethingInAside;
  }
}
```

And use it like this to call your components in `navbar`:

```
<NavBar @toggleSomethingInAside={{this.toggleShowSomethingInAside}} />
<NavAside @showSomethingInAside={{this.showSomethingInAside}} />
```

Then inside `nav-bar` you can use the action:

```
<button type="button" {{on "click" @toggleSomethingInAside}}>
  show something in aside
</button>
```

And inside `nav-aside` you can use the boolean:

```
{{#if @showSomethingInAside}}
  This can be toggled by the button in the other component
{{/if}}
```

---

So you see the solution is to always keep the state in the right place. If multiple components share a state (because one changes it and the other reads it) that state belongs in neither component but a common ancestor component.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, after trying to find a solution, I finally figured what actions up data down meant...